# Why not all two spaces replaced with tab key?

Tags: retab

Here is my sample file:

```
cat test
x1  x2  x3
x  x  x
```

All spaces contain two spaces in the test file,convert all the spaces into tab in vim :

```
:set ts=2 sts=2 noet
:retab!
```

Strange thing happens that not all two spaces converted into tab.

[image]

Why the first two spaces in second line did not converted into `tab`--(^I) ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it looks like it depends on `tabstop` counted from the line beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because not all sequences of two spaces end on a column that is multiple of 2 (your tab stop.)

Perhaps it's easier to reason about this if you consider a tab stop of 8. If you `:retab!` your buffer with it, not all sequences of 8 spaces will be replaced with tabs, only those that end in columns that are multiple of 8. On the other hand, sequences *shorter* than 8 spaces might still be converted to a tab, as long as they also end on a column that is multiple of 8. (This last effect doesn't happen with a tab stop of 2, since you would need multiple spaces shorter than the tab stop and you can't have that with only two.)